# Имеется программа, которая под догадкам написана на js. Хочу поменять в ней некоторые детали интерфейса по типу фона и значков

Tags: javascript

Имеется программа, содержащая множество Qt5.dll файлов и огромнейшее кол-во библиотек >_< Приложение запускается через exe. (Еще есть папка с файлами js и css, но, похоже, это для возможности включать приложение на телефонах). В общем я хочу поменять интерфейс - сменить цвет фона, изменить расположение кнопок и их вид. Можно ли это сделать через какую-то программу? :с (Покопавшись во всех файлах, нашел изображения, но они не встречаются в PC версии приложения ...)

Answer (score -1):

ответ: **ДА, МОЖНО**.
но перед тем как начать *что-то* переделывать, предлагаю Вам окунуться в прошлое и постараться прокрутить у себя в голове все уроки информатики, так как они помогут Вам в программировании. если же такой возможности нет, то можете просто посмотреть ролик "JS за 10 минут от А до Я" и смело начинать разработку.
с Уважением

Comment: Лишь бы чтото написать.... А что без разницы.... JS за 10 иин... Супер... Тем более, что это не JS